# How base class is collected by GC?

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
baseclass bc = new derivedclass();
```

Will the base class object be created in this case? If yes how will the GC know that it is being used (as it does not have any variable pointing to it)? How does the GC handle this?

EDIT : When I set bc = null, Both the base and derived class destructors are called. If no base object is created, how is it calling base class destructor?

How can the destuctor be called when there is no base object?
This is what MSDN says about destructor : "Destructors are used to destruct instances of classes".

Comment: Do you have an actual problem, or are you just asking because of general intrest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, only an instance of the derived class is created. That will contain all of the fields of the base class, of course, but it isn't a separate object. There's nothing to be garbage collected.

Note that `bc` is just a variable, not an object. `bc` itself doesn't need to be garbage collected - it's just that it can *prevent* the garbage collection of the variable whose value it refers to if it might be read again. (If nothing is ever going to read from `bc` again, and you're not running under the debugger, it won't prevent the object from being garbage collected.)

Comment: but the base class constructor is also called in this case. Does not that create a new base class object?

Comment: When I set bc = null, Both the base and derived class destructors are called. If no base object is created, how is it calling base class destructor?

Comment: @syd: The constructor call is effectively part of the initialization of the derived object. It doesn't create a *separate* object. Setting `bc` to null does *not* call a destructor/finalizer immediately - C# doesn't have deterministic finalization. However, when the derived class finalizer is called, that automatically calls the base class finalizer. (Look at the IL for the derived class finalizer.) I suspect you're trying to think in C++, which doesn't always fit :)

Comment: But how can the destuctor be called when there is no base object? This is what MSDN says : Destructors are used to destruct instances of classes.

Comment: @syd: The instance of the derived class *is* an instance of the base class. It's just that there's no *separate* instance of the base class. Just as the constructor of the base class is used to initialize the "base class portion" of the object, the finalizer in the base class is used to perform any cleanup required for the "base class portion" of the object on finalization. Note that the finalizer *isn't* responsible for "freeing" the object from memory etc. It's just extra cleanup (and very rarely needed).